# Interactive application running through Windows service

Tags: powershell

I was trying to run a menu based .net application through windows service.  The application needs to be started by pressing Alt+P and Alt+S.   I have built Powershell script to do this.  When run this script in desktop session then it works fine but when i put it through windows service it is failing during AppActivate step.   Could someone help on how to achieve this?  These are legacy application and would like to run these as is through windows service as a background rather than running through user session.

Here is the snippet of the powershell code

```
add-type -AssemblyName microsoft.VisualBasic
add-type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

##  Application Name 

$Application="D:\Application Services\File Transfer\x86\Transfer.exe"
$ProgramName="Transfer"

### Validating whether the application already running
"Working..." | Out-File -Append "C:\temp\Update.log"

while ($true) 
{
    $Running = Get-Process $ProgramName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if ($Running -eq $null) 
    {
      ##  Start the process
      $Proc = Start-Process $Application

      ##  Wait for the process to appear
      Start-sleep -seconds 5

      while ( $Proc.Id -eq $null) {

           $Proc = Get-Process $ProgramName
      }

     "Process Information " +  $Proc.Id | Out-File -Append "C:\temp\Update.log"

      ##  Get the Handle of the Application
      ##$WindowHandle = Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle -Match $ProgramName } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MainWindowHandle

      ##  Point the focus to the Given application
      "[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate(" + $Proc.Id + ")" | Out-File -Append "C:\temp\Update.log"

    [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("Transfer")

     Start-sleep -seconds 5

     "Send Keys " | Out-File -Append "C:\temp\Update.log"
     ##  Pass the Key control to Start the application
     [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("%{p}s")

         "Started " + $Proc.Id + "  " + $Succ  | Out-File -Append "C:\temp\Update.log"
    }
 }
```

When run this code through Windows Service, application get invoked but it is not starting the application and throwing below error

```
Exception calling "AppActivate" with "1" argument(s): "Process '{0}' was not found."
At C:\temp\TransferApp.ps1:38 char:4
+          [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("Transfer")
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException
 
Exception calling "SendWait" with "1" argument(s): "Access is denied"
At C:\temp\TransferApp.ps1:48 char:3
+      $Succ=[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("%{p}s")
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Win32Exception
```

Comment: PowerShell always runs in the user context that started it. You cannot run an interactive GUI based app, without a user context, this is Windows proper, not a PowerShell thing. Services are not a user context. Also, PowerShell is really not the best for GUI automation. It's better to look to tools like AutoIT, even using that with PowerShell, but this still does not subvert/supplant what Windows proper requires. It's really not a thing to use a service to run interactive apps. Interactive specifically means a user must interact with active app, so not possible for a background process.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback